# How to pass data in object_ptr format in python-telegram library

Tags: python, json, api, telegram, tdlib

In `python-telegram` lib; I have a problem with calling methods which require data in `object_ptr` data type (You can read about it in `tdlib` documentation)

Exactly my problem is in `addContact` method. How should I pass data in `params` ?

I act like this:

```py
result = t.call_method('addContact',params={'contact' : { 'phone_number' : 'some number' , 'first_name' : 'some name' , 'last_name' : 'some thing' , 'vcard' : '' , 'user_id' : 0 } , 'share_phone_number' : False})
result.wait()
print(result.update)
```

The `print` result is `None` & no contact is added.

Where is the problem?

This links may be useful:

[TDLib addContact Class Reference](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/docs/classtd_1_1td__api_1_1add_contact.html)

[TDLib contact Class Reference](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/docs/classtd_1_1td__api_1_1contact.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly I found the solution

I should use `importContacts` method to add contacts by phone number and without knowing user ID.

Also, printing `result.error_info` will be useful